# web3 wallet connecting working fine on desktop browser but not on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3js, web3modal

i am new in web3 learning, am trying to get account address of user when they authenticate with their crpto wallet.for this i had used following code (i got it from google) which works fine on desktop browser but on mobile its not working even i had installed metamask application in mobile phone. here is my code

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('walletconnectBtnHere').addEventListener('click', event => {
  let accountsOnEnable = await ethereum.request({ method: "eth_accounts" });
  let address = accountsOnEnable[0];
  address = address.toLowerCase();
  alert("Address: " + address);
});
<script>`
<button id="walletconnectBtnHere">Connect Wallet<button/>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoking wallet functions on mobile will only work in MetaMask built-in browser. Head to MM application, and use its internal browser.

Comment: so how i can connect with wallet with mobile ? i dun know about MM application can u please recommend article

Comment: Take a look on that: https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/6356387482523-How-to-use-the-MetaMask-Mobile-Browser

Comment: anyother solution sir ? because from website i cant force users to use meta mask built in browser to access my application to authenticate

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other way at the moment :(

Comment: wallet connect provides a way to connect metamask wallet from any browser